# How to auto refresh div contents contain php variables?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I created a page named `queries.php`

```
<?php
require("connection.inc.php");
$query = "SELECT SUM(john), SUM(robert), COUNT(school) FROM election";
$result = mysql_db_query($db, $query, $connection) or
die("query error!");

$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$john = number_format($data[0], 0,',','.');     
$robert = number_format($data[1], 0,',','.');
$school = $data[2];
$total = $john + $robert;
$remaining_school = 524 - $school;
$percentage_john = round(($john*100/$total),2);
$percentage_robert = round(($robert*100/$total),2);
?>
```

Then I display the data in `display.php`
The data displayed well and nothing error, I tried a couple of tricks to auto refresh the container using jquery but failed.
Here is my `display.php` page:

```
<?php
include("queries.php");
?>

<div id="totaljohn"> // <--- the div id taken from css layout
<h9>John: <?php echo $john; ?> <br> (<?php echo $percentage_john; ?> %)</h9>
</div>

<div id="totalrobert">
<h9>Robert: <?php echo $robert; ?><br> (<?php echo $percentage_robert; ?> %)</h9>
</div>

<div id="totalboth">
<h4>Total : <?php echo $total; ?> Suara</h4>
</div>

<div id="totalschool">
<h4>Total School attending : <?php echo $school; ?> Schools</h4>
</div>

<div id="remaining_schools">
<h4>Remaining Schools: <?php echo $remaining_school; ?> of 524 schools</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: `I tried a couple of tricks to auto refresh the container`, where is the code?

Comment: do you want to do this with Javascript?

Comment: I added a json_encode at the end of query page
`echo json_encode(array('john'=>$john, 'robert'=>$robert, 'school'=>$school, 'total'=>$total, 'remaining'=>$remaining_school, 'p_john'=>$percent_john, 'p_robert'=>$percent_robert));`

Comment: my javascript page:

 `$(document).ready(fucntion() {
 done();
 });
  function done(){
   setTimeout(function){
   updates();
   done();
  }, 200);
 }

 function update(){

 $.getJSON("autorefresh.php", function(data)){
  $("ul").empty();
  $.each(data.result, function(){
   $("ul").append("<li>"+this['john']+"</li>"+"<li>"+this['robert']+"</li>"+"<li>"+this['school']+"<li>"+this['total']+"<li>"+this['remaining']+"<li>"+this['p_john']+"<li>"+this['p_robert']+"</li> </br>");

  });
  });
  }`

Comment: in my display page I used `<ul></ul>` instead of div and h4 I posted above

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks good.  Is your database connected?  Is your SQL correct?  Are there records in the database returned for your query?

Comment: yes it's connected, the codes i posted are working codes. My problem is I don't know how autorefresh the data without reloading the page. I tried some jquery tutorials but didn't do what I wanted.

Comment: Do you mean auto-refresh with AJAX?

Comment: yes, I tried ajax with looping display and it worked. but when I tried to this kind of display (non looping), nothing displayed.

Comment: I added a json_encode at the end of query page `echo json_encode(array('john'=>$john, 'robert'=>$robert, 'school'=>$school, 'total'=>$total, 'remaining'=>$remaining_school, 'p_john'=>$percent_john, 'p_robert'=>$percent_robert));` and the array data displayed well.